# .htaccess redirect in folder on domain affects same named folder in subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I recently changed a site I've developed to use a Wildcard SSL certificate but I'm having an issue with .htaccess ReWrites in the domain.com/projects folder affecting the cms.domain.com/projects folder.

In the www.domain.com/projects folder is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /projects/project.php?id=$1 [L]
```

When an SEO friendly project url e.g. www.domain.com/projects/project-title gets sent to this folder it is directed to the project.php page where it can be displayed.

This works fine, but I came across a problem in the subdomain cms.domain.com/projects, this folder and all its contents display a 404 error, even though all the files are there. I know this .htaccess file is the issue because I have changed the cms.domain/projects folder name and the sub directories appear and I've also removed the code from the .htaccess file and the cms.domain.com/projects folder appears.

I have tried, many of the suggestions found here and else where adding RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ and denying the cms.domain.com url but nothing works, and the projects folder in the cms remains stubbornly in 404 land. I've been looking at this for several days and have found nothing similar on the Interweb.  Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for all the replies so far.

Comment: Add a RewriteCond that checks the host name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewritecond how to check if on Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785475/rewritecond-how-to-check-if-on-domain)